# Code Analysis Warning CA2213 - Call Dispose() on IDisposable backing field

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, fxcop, c#-6.0

Wanted to post this, even though I figured it out as I was writing the question.  Will post answer below.

Getting the following warning with VS Code Analysis:

> Warning   CA2213  'DBConn' contains field 'DBConn.k__BackingField' that is of IDisposable type: 'SqlConnection'. Change the Dispose method on 'DBConn' to call Dispose or Close on this field.

But my code **does** call Dispose() on the DBConn property.  Does it not on the backing field?  I have other instances like this - where I am disposing of where the compiler does not throw this warning.  This is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;    

namespace TheProgramSpace
{
    public sealed class DBConn : IDisposable
    {
        // class containing the database and its connection
        public SqlConnection TheConn { get; }
        public string DbPath { get; }
        public string DbName { get; }


        public DBConn(ProgInstance FPI)
        {
            // constructs new SQLConnection            
            DbPath = FPI.dbPath;
            DbName = FPI.dbName;

            string connString = "Data Source = " + DbPath + "; Initial Catalog =" + DbName + "; Integrated Security = True; "
              + "Connect Timeout = 30; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = False; "
              + "ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover = False";                     

            TheConn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {            
            TheConn.Dispose();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  You'd get a _different_ compiler warning prior to C# 6 since you must provide a setter for automatic properties.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1798055/code-analysis-rule-ca2213-disposablefieldsshouldbedisposed-doesnt-understand-read-only-auto-properties-being-disposed) in FxCop that will be fixed in a future release.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is not a problem with your code.  `Dispose` *will* be called on the underlying backing field.  This is a [known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4077) in FxCop that surfaced with the introduction of "getter-only" automatic properties which were introduced in C# 6.  For now, you can either [suppress the warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx) with an attribute on the class or just ignore it until it's fixed in FxCop.

Comment: Dead link to MS Connect

Comment: @timelmer Thanks - Fixed.

Comment: Has this still not been fixed?

Answer (score 18):

The reason is that `TheConn`, because it did not have a `set` accessor, was read-only.  Changing the property declaration to

```
public SqlConnection TheConn { get; private set; }
```

solved the problem.