# Change the Dispose method on 'ReproClass' to call Dispose or Close on this field

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem that was not present until the most recent VS2019 update (16.8.1)

```
public class ReproClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Mutex _mtx = new Mutex();
    public void Dispose() => _mtx?.Dispose();
}
```

produces:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CA2213  'ReproClass' contains field 'ReproClass._mtx' that is of
> IDisposable type: 'Mutex'. Change the Dispose method on 'ReproClass'
> to call Dispose or Close on this
> field.    ShutterModeler  path_to\ReproClass.cs   10  Active

I'm using "Code Analysis" with "Microsoft Manager Miniumum Rules" set.

This seems related to [Code Analysis Warning CA2213 - Call Dispose() on IDisposable backing field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583417/code-analysis-warning-ca2213-call-dispose-on-idisposable-backing-field) but I'm not using FXcop nor a property.

How to solve this ?

Comment: I'm curious.... does the problem go away if you remove the `?` symbol?

Comment: Don't take all warnings for granted, use your common sense and don't fear about suppressing.

Comment: I'm with @JohnWu here. You know that that `_mtx` cannot be null in the provided example so I'd suggest removing the `?` (null propagation operator).

Comment: @JohnWu Indeed, the Error goes away with the null check propagator being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by John Wu, the null propagation operator was the culprit.
CA2213 goes away in this implementation:

```
public class ReproClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Mutex _mtx = new Mutex();
    public void Dispose() => _mtx.Dispose();
}
```

This implementation reduces the cyclomatic complexity to 1, which is desired in `Dispose()`.